# Print char* character by character

Tags: c++, for-loop, char

I'm using an unconventional version of C++ which lacks string, cin, and cout.
I use a function call `uart_printf()` to send serial data with my calculator to my phone throught bluetooth module but I have an imposed baudrate of 115200 wicth is too high for the module so to solve that I need to send an char* letter by letter.
So here is my actual code:

```
char input2[90] = {0};
nio_getsn(input2,90);
uart_printf("$");
uart_printf("#");
uart_printf("$");
int num = numberOfCharsInArray(input2);
for(char* it = input2; *it; ++it) {
      uart_printf("%s",it);
}
uart_printf("\r");
uart_printf("\n");
```

But this give me that if I send, for example, 12345:

> $#$1 2 3 4 2 3 42 3 4 3 43 4 44

I have already tried this but not performing so well:

```
for(char* it = input2; *it; ++it) {
    uart_printf("%s",it);
}
```

> $#$ïéÈ¯Ýþ§
>   �8aó­öx½²=çVóm×0ígÙuRAJàÌÆAš¶øY¯çšÏf¯Ò"Œß¾»¥Å· ÐI½}~·{oþý›…Ýz¹üÛ³äËÎëKüºÍtå|    ã¡íñ¼¾£œ,2ý²®Þ«ÿ�#�ûíN”
>   ØÍbùöœ›es»÷öþ†i?·B·ŽUÊMãÉÿZk¾Ãû?"\¢º'îìÀŸöeýç“žððµšøx½s§Ÿ\ÆAš¶øY¯çšÏf¯Ò"Œß¾»¥Å· ÐI½}~·{oþý›…Ýz¹üÛ³äËÎëKüºÍtå|   ã¡íñ¼¾£œ,2ý²®Þ«ÿ�#�ûíN”
>   ØÍbùöœ›es»÷öþ†i?·B·ŽUÊMãÉÿZk¾Ãû?"\¢º'îìÀŸöeýç“žððµšøx½s§Ÿ\JàÌÆAš¶øY¯çšÏf¯Ò"Œß¾»¥Å· ÐI½}~·{oþý›…Ýz¹üÛ³äËÎëKüºÍtå|    ã¡íñ¼¾£œ,2ý²®Þ«ÿ�#�ûíN”
>   ØÍbùöœ›es»÷öþ†i?·B·ŽUÊMãÉÿZk¾Ãû?"\¢º'îìÀŸöeýç“žððµšøx½s§Ÿ\JàÌÆAš¶øY¯çšÏf¯Ò"Œß¾»¥Å· ÐI½}~·{oþý›…Ýz¹üÛ³äËÎëKüºÍtå|    ã¡íñ¼¾£œ,2ý²®Þ«ÿ�#�ûíN”
>   ØÍbùöœ›es»÷öþ†i?·B·ŽUÊMãÉÿZk¾Ãû?"\¢º'îìÀŸöeýç“žððµšøx½s§Ÿ\JàÌÆAš¶øY¯çšÏf¯Ò"Œß¾»¥Å· ÐI½}~·{oþý›…Ýz¹üÛ³äËÎëKüºÍtå|    ã¡íñ¼¾£œ,2ý²®Þ«ÿ�#�ûíN”
>   ØÍbùöœ›es»÷öþ†i?·B·ŽUÊMãÉÿZk¾Ãû?"\¢º'îìÀŸöeýç“žððµšøx½s§Ÿ\JàÌÆAš¶øY¯çšÏf¯Ò"Œß¾»¥Å· ÐI½}~·{oþý›…Ýz¹üÛ³äËÎëKüºÍtå|    ã¡íñ¼¾£œ,2ý²®Þ«ÿ�#�ûíN”
>   ØÍbùöœ›es»÷öþ†i?·B·ŽUÊMãÉÿZk¾Ãû?"\¢º'îìÀŸöeýç“žððµšøx½s§Ÿ\JàÌÆAš¶øY¯çšÏf¯Ò"Œß¾»¥Å· ÐI½}~·{oþý›…Ýz¹üÛ³äËÎëKüºÍtå|    ã¡íñ¼¾£œ,2ý²®Þ«ÿ�#�ûíN”
>   ØÍbùöœ›es»÷öþ†i?·B·ŽUÊMãÉÿZk¾Ãû?"\¢º'îìÀŸöeýç“žððµšøx½s§Ÿ\

It should output 12345.

I'm stuck on this for my program it's the last step.

Comment: s/`uart_printf("%s",it);`/`uart_printf("%c",*it);`

Comment: If compiling with GCC, there's a good chance you can get a warning about this.

Comment: That trash looks like a baud rate mismatch.

Comment: 1. _ "It should output 12345."_ - No. More like `123452345345455` 2. Do you have an `uart_putc`? 3. `while ( *p ) uart_putc( *p++, stdout );`

Answer (score 1):

According to [`printf()` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) you should be using the `%c` specifier since you are printing individual `char`. The `%s` specifier is for printing a string of characters.